# Jquery - Como passar uma variável para um seletor de jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá, sou novo aqui (assim como muito novo em conhecimentos de js e jquery). Eu estou tentando passar o resultado de uma variável para um seletor jquery. Mais especificamente eu estou querendo passar (por meio do evento click) o nome de um id (dentre diversos existentes, pois são criados dinamicamente) para uma variável. E depois de capturado este id, eu possa utilizá-lo como seletor (para me referenciar à classes ou id's de mesmo nome). Passo o código do que queria fazer:

```
        $( function() {
            $('#geral :input').click(function(){
            var VARIAVEL = $(this).attr('id');

            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('???VARIÁVEL???" :input').prop('checked','checked');
            } else {
               $('???VARIÁVEL??? :input').removeAttr('checked');
            }
        });
```

Reforçando... esta variável seria ora usada para selecionar "id's" e ora "class's"... Então imagino o uso do "." e do "#" em conjunto com ela...
Talvez o problema seja muito básico, mas saber isto vai me socorrer de longas (muito longas) horas de pesquisas infrutíferas pela internet.

A pedidos vou colar parte do código do formulário aqui, que não está concluído e necessita de complementos (mas ainda querendo saber sobre a dúvida inicial):

```
    echo "<div id='geral'>";
    echo    "<form action='addmembro.php' method='post'>";
    echo      "<b><label for='estadoID'>Relação: </label></b><br>";
                foreach($estado_obtido as $indiceestado => $valorestado):
                $estado=mb_strtoupper($valorestado["estado_estado"], "UTF-8");
                $estado1=$valorestado["estado_estado"];
                $uf=$valorestado["estado_uf"];
                echo  "<div  class='estados'>"
                    . "<input id='{$uf}' type='checkbox' name='{}' value='{}'>"
                    . "<b><label>{$estado} </label></b><br>";                       
                    foreach($regiao_obtida as $indiceregiao => $valorregiao):
                    $regiao1=$valorregiao["mesorregiao_mesorregiao"];
                    $codregiao=$valorregiao["mesorregiao_cod2"];
                    $estado2=$valorregiao["mesorregiao_estado"];
                            if($estado2==$estado1):
                                echo  "<div class='regioes'>"
                                    . "<input  id='{$codregiao}' type='checkbox' name='{}' value='{}'>"
                                    . "<b><label'>{$regiao1} - {$estado}</label></b><br>";                                
                                foreach ($cidade_obtida as $indicecidade => $valorcidade):
                                $municipio=$valorcidade["regiao_municipio"];
                                $codmunicipio=$valorcidade["regiao_codmunicipio"];
                                $regiao2=$valorcidade["regiao_regiao"];    
                                    if($regiao2==$regiao1):
                                        echo  "<div  class='{$codregiao}'>"
                                            . "<input id='{$codmunicipio}' type='checkbox' name='' value=''>"
                                            . "<label>{$municipio} - {$estado2}</label>"
                                            . "</div>";
```

Obrigado!!

Comment: Que elemento é esse `$('???VARIÁVEL???" :input')`? não é o mesmo que o `$(this)`? Ou seja, bastaria `$(this).prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));`

Comment: Você tem um input dentro de outro?! Ou por acaso vários elementos com o mesmo ID? Nada disso é permitido.

Comment: Olá, Sérgio..! Na verdade não dá pra usar o this  (acho). São 140 opções, com 6000 sub opções. Cada grupo e subgrupo de check foi criado dinamicamente recebendo nomes específicos. Tudo "abraçado" por uma div com id de nome "geral". Eu consigo capturar o nome de cada id pelo evento "click", mas pra chegar até estes id's que estão dentro da div "geral", eu precisaria levar o nome de seus respectivos id's para o seletor... este seletor vai "acionar" os "sub-ids" e "sub-classes"... por isto que acho que não dá pra ser com "this"... e sim já dizer qual o respectivo id/classe que quero chegar. Obg!

Comment: Oi Favareto. Não... Mas tenho inputs dentro de "div's" e "sub div's"... no html puro os inputs estão um abaixo do outro... mas na realidade existem "principais" e "subsidiários" digamos assim... Obrigado pelo interesse!

Comment: Depois se alguém puder me instruir em como editar o título da postagem, seria legal... O final não é "seletor de seletor" e sim "seletor de jquery".. me atrapalhei na hora de escrever..! Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta e incluir a estrutura do seu HTML? Pode ser um trecho, um grupo desses de divs e subdivs. Porque eu ainda acho que dá pra resolver sem precisar montar um seletor. Mas só para esclarecer a sua dúvida, você pode concatenar strings e variáveis com o operador `+`, assim: `var algo = variavel + 'string' + outraVar + 'outra string';`

Comment: Se possível, tente também explicar melhor o que você está tentando fazer. Você quer marcar/desmarcar um checkbox, e outros que dependam dele acompanhem automaticamente?

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção @bfavaretto!! Ok, quanto à concatenação, mas eu gostaria de saber se uma variável pode ser usada como seletor. E caso sim, qual seria a sintaxe (supondo ser tratado como id e classe). Mas ok, eu vou colar parte do código restante pra vc ter uma idéia.

Answer (score 4):

Considerando a sua solução, ainda dá pra simplificar bem o código:

```
$( function() {
    $('#geral :input').click(function(){

        // 1. não usar caixa alta em nomes de var
        // 2. não precisa de jQuery para pegar o id, use this.id
        var seletor = '.' + this.id + ' :input';

        // Como o Sergio tinha sugerido
        var estado = $(this).prop('checked');
        $(seletor).prop('checked', estado);

    } // faltava fechar o listener de click
});
```

Comment: Obrigado @bfavaretto pela dica (A caixa alta foi apenas para chamar a atenção para o ponto do texto que eu tinha interesse em solucionar). Agradeço ao Fábio, mas é que eu precisava saber justamente o passo anterior. Como falei, era a obtenção de id's dinâmicos. Por isto meu desejo em armazená-los em variáveis. Abraços

Answer (score 1):

Consegui achar a solução! Obrigado a quem se interessou! Para passar uma variável para o seletor jquery basta utilizar concatenação simples. Na hipótese do seletor precisar referenciar uma classe pode ser feito assim:

```
    $( function() {
        $('#geral :input').click(function(){
        var VARIAVEL = $(this).attr('id');

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('.' + VARIAVEL + ' :input').prop('checked','checked');//(SOLUÇÃO AQUI!)
        } else {
            $('.' + VARIAVEL + ' :input').removeAttr('checked');//(E AQUI!)
        }
    });
```

(E para referenciar-se a um id, apenas troca-se o '.', para '#', obviamente.)

Uma atenção especial vai para os espaçamentos (motivo do meu erro em muitas tentativas). O 'input' teve que vir com o espaço antes dos 'dois pontos'(:), pois senão o código é lido assim: 
".VARIAVEL:input" (como uma instrução única - a qual não existe).

;)